# How to say catcall in Chinese? “Catcall” 怎么翻译？

Tags: translation

I'm trying to say "catcall" or "catcalling" in Chinese (as in, for example, a woman walking in a city street, a man yells something at her, typically degrading and commenting on her looks, etc), but all dictionaries I've found use "catcall" as meaning to hiss or yell, which isn't quite the meaning I'm going for here. The translations I've found include: 不满之声,嘘声,口哨聲, and some others, but none of those really seem right from translating them into English. How would I translate that?

Comment: Your example  (as in, for example, a woman walking in a city street, a man yells something at her, typically degrading and commenting on her looks, etc) sounds like **harrassment**, which is close to 骚扰 in Chinese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to be some form of **挑逗**.

---

For instance, [wolf-whistle](http://dict.youdao.com/w/wolf-whistling), which is one of the most common forms of catcalling that I can think of, is rendered as:

> (挑逗地)吹口哨

or

> 朝…吹口哨挑逗

---

[【超模中槍】Catcall是性騷擾？受害者：像背後解開比堅尼般羞辱](https://www.hk01.com/%E7%9F%A5%E6%80%A7%E5%A5%B3%E7%94%9F/144329/%E8%B6%85%E6%A8%A1%E4%B8%AD%E6%A7%8D-catcall%E6%98%AF%E6%80%A7%E9%A8%B7%E6%93%BE-%E5%8F%97%E5%AE%B3%E8%80%85-%E5%83%8F%E8%83%8C%E5%BE%8C%E8%A7%A3%E9%96%8B%E6%AF%94%E5%A0%85%E5%B0%BC%E8%88%AC%E7%BE%9E%E8%BE%B1) defines catcalling as:

> 「Catcalling」街頭挑逗

although it does also mention

> 「Catcalling」，要是翻譯為「街頭挑逗」，其實也不夠傳神。

---

[勇于向街头骚扰说“不”](https://share.america.gov/zh-hans/hollaback-against-street-harassment/) writes it as:

> 布鲁克林（Brooklyn）的一个禁止“挑逗搭讪”（catcalling）的标牌。

Answer (score 0):

I saw *catcall* has two basic meanings, one of them is complaint on shows, that could be translated as 喝倒彩。There are certain ways you could do that in a theater, you can make sounds like **tòng** three times in a row, or you can also pronounce 噫 with a long fading tail. But notice, in a [相声](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangsheng) show, such catcalls could be praise because it is a much casual place.

It is obvious, however, that you are asking for the translation of its other meaning. Unfortunately, it is hard to find such short correspondence in Chinese. What you could do is describing catcall like the following

> 当街耍流氓，（言语）调戏妇女